# Safe alternatives to using iptables redirection for database

Tags: mysql, iptables, accounting, freeradius

We are using MySQL for our FreeRADIUS user store and accounting database for our web application.

I would like to separate the accounting portion of the database, move it to a new server to lighten the database reads and rights, among other things.

My first thought was redirecting the accounting portion of the NAS traffic to another server via iptables and storing it in a separate database.

This seems hacky at best, I am worried about the consistency of the accounting stream.

Has anyone come across similar issues before?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by redirect NAS traffic?  Are the mysql databases stored on the NAS, or what?  Why would you need to do some kind of redirection with iptables, why couldn't you just mount another volume?

Comment: Network Access Servers or Broadband Aggregaters, Cisco 7200s.

Answer (score 1):

I think a load balancer would be the most common tool to help lighten the load, but you may want to look into MySql Proxy.

There are some interesting things you can do with it; however, I would test thoroughly and load test before putting it in production use.

MySql Proxy: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy

Comment: I will check it out. I would prefer to not put anything between our Authenticating RADIUS and NAS servers for the sake of another single point of failure and added issues, but I may have no other options. Thanks